# exctract values by column from arrays of arrays, seperated in different arrays

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array of arrays as it is shown :
[image: array of arrays]

I want to collect all the values of the first column (118,117,115 etc) but seperated in different array for values that are in different arrays on my initial array of arrays. In more detail I want to have my value as:

```
array([118,117,115,...]),
array([461,460,459,...])
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the time to read this post on how to provide a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is normally not helpful to place your text in an image. You force other people to type out your text, instead of being able to copy and paste. With that said,

Accessing information in numpy arrays is an extremely useful skill and something worth reading several tutorials about. I would google numpy and read how to use numpy arrays. For example,

```
# This is similar to your data, two 3x2 arrays. Here I put them in one large array. 
data = np.array([[[1,2],
                  [3,4],
                  [5,6]],
                 [[7,8],
                  [9,10],
                  [11,12]]])

print(data.shape)  # There are three axis, which indicate how data is accessed. 
                   # This also shows how much data is in each axis. 
print(data[0,0,0]) # Access the value "1", located at 0,0,0 in the array. 

print(data[0])     # Access the first 3x2 array. 

print(data[1,0])   # Access the second 3x2 and then the first row of that. 

print(data[1,0:2]) # Access the second 3x2 and the 0th and 1st rows. 

print(data[:,:,0]) # Access both arrays, all rows, and only the 0th column.
```

Comment: sorry for the image... Your suggestion works fine, it is right, although it doesn't worked for me but something else is the problem.It returns me the error :TypeError list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Comment: What error? You never gave an error. In fact, you never even gave your code. If you would like, try to edit your question, delete the image, put a code block of some "minimal working code" and the error you are getting that you did not expect.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for you:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = [
    np.array([[[1,2]],[[3,4]]]),
    np.array([[[5,6]],[[7,8]]]),
]

[x[:,:,0].flatten() for x in arr]
```

Out:

```
[array([1, 3]), array([5, 7])]
```